# adding another marker on google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, marker, jquery-gmap3

I have been trying all day to simply add another marker to my google map but failing all the time. Can someone point me on how this is done please?

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.google-maps').gmap3({
                map:{
                    address: "PL1 3LF",
                    options:{
                        zoom: 14,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                        mapTypeControl: false,
                        mapTypeControlOptions: {
                            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DEFAULT
                        },
                        navigationControl: true,
                        scrollwheel: false,
                        streetViewControl: false
                    }
                },
                marker:{
                    address: "PL1 3LF"
                },marker:{
                    address: "PL1 3qq"
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying changing

```
marker:{
  address: "PL1 3LF"
},marker:{
  address: "PL1 3qq"
}
```

To

```
marker:{
    values:[
      {address:"PL1 3qq"},
      {address:"PL1 3LF"}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
marker:{
    values:[
      {address:"PL1 3LF"},
      {address:PL1 3qq}
    ]
}
```